# Cant populate table with images using razor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ImageName' and no accessible extension method 'ImageName' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Is the current error I am getting, However the way im going about this seems to be wrong if anyone can help or point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. (Aslo I am using .net core 2.1 since my school computers do not support later versions :/)

Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Lab2Phase1.Models.Car>  

@{  
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";  
}  

<strong>Index</strong>  

<p>  
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>  
</p>  
<div class="col-md-8">
    <form action="/Cars" method="post">
        @Html.TextBox("search")
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<table class="table">  
    <thead>  
        <tr>  
            <th>  
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)  
            </th>  
            <th>  
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)  
            </th>  
            <th>  
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TopSpeed)  
            </th>  
            <th>  
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageName)
            </th>  
            <th></th>  
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
@foreach (var item in Model) {  
        <tr>  
            <td>  
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TopSpeed)  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                <img src="~/Content/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ImageName)" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>  
            </td>  
            <td>  
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |  
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')" })  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
}  
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

Here is the controller:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using Lab2Phase1.Models;  
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;  
using Lab2Phase1.CarsContext;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Lab2Phase1.Controllers  
{  
    public class CarsController : Controller  
    {  

        EFDataContext _dbContext = new EFDataContext();  
        public IActionResult Cars()  
        {  
            var data = this._dbContext.Cars.ToList();

            return View(data);          
        }  

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Cars(string search)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("boot");
            //search = Request.Form["search"].ToString(); 
            var data = _dbContext.Cars.Where(c => c.Model.Contains(search));


            return View(data);          
        }  

        public IActionResult Create()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  

        [HttpPost]  
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("Id,Model,TopSpeed,ImageName")]Car model)  
        {  
            ModelState.Remove("Id");
            model.Model = Request.Form["Model"];
            model.TopSpeed = Request.Form["TopSpeed"];
            model.ImageName = Request.Form["ImageName"];

            if (ModelState.IsValid)  
            {  
                _dbContext.Cars.Add(model);  
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();  
                return RedirectToAction("cars");  
            }  
            return View();  
        }  

        public IActionResult Edit(int id)  
        {  
            Car data = _dbContext.Cars.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();  
            return View("Create", data);  
        }  

        [HttpPost]  
        public IActionResult Edit(Car model)  
        {  
            ModelState.Remove("Id");
            model.Id = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["Id"]);
            model.Model = Request.Form["Model"];
            model.TopSpeed = Request.Form["TopSpeed"];
            model.ImageName = Request.Form["ImageName"];

            if (ModelState.IsValid)  
            {  
                _dbContext.Cars.Update(model);  
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();  
                return RedirectToAction("cars");  
            }  
            return View("Create", model);  
        }  

        public IActionResult Delete(int id)  
        {  
            Car data = _dbContext.Cars.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();  
            if (data != null)  
            {  
                _dbContext.Cars.Remove(data);  
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();  
            }  
            return RedirectToAction("cars");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here's the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;  

namespace Lab2Phase1.Models  
{  
    public class Car  
    {  
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Model { get; set; }  
        public string TopSpeed { get; set; }  

        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img src="~/Content/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ImageName)" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>`

should be

`<img src="~/Content/images/@(item.ImageName)" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>`

Assuming your `ImageName` is a file name with extention, available in that path.